# ¿Dónde están definidas las rutas de login en una aplicación Laravel Jetstream?

Tags: laravel, web, jetstream

estoy estudiando como hacer una página web con Laravel Jetstream pero al momento de ver el archivo web.php me doy cuenta que solo hay una ruta definida no están los login y aún así funcionan mi pregunta es: dónde se encuentran las rutas del Login definidas? O se pueden definir de otra manera? Este es el código del archivo web

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware([
   'auth:sanctum',
  
config('jetstream.auth_session'),
'verified'
])->group(function () {
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: Pero que es lo que quieres hacer? Las rutas como tal son `{{ route('login') }}` y `{{ route('register') }}`, puedes ver como las llaman en el archivo `resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php`.

Comment: @OCHOA es que quiero saber en donde estan definidas porque yo aprendi que cada ruta de la aplicacion se deben de definir en el web.php y por eso me causa conflicto ver que las rutas login de jetstream no estan, entonces me gustaria saber donde estan las rutas para poder entender mejor

Comment: [Y para que?](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FOJGKaCWQA4mzsJ?format=jpg&name=900x900), deben estar en el core, yo creo que si comienzas a tocar esos archivos lo que pasará es que te vas a estresar al no entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las rutas como tal son `{{ route('login') }}` y `{{ route('register') }}` puedes ver como las llaman en el archivo `resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php`

Las rutas están definidas en `vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php`

Las rutas de Jetstream no se muestran como tal en el **routes/web.php** pero se manejan con el Middleware Auth.

Pero como ya te lo comenté antes, lo mejor es entender como y donde las puedes "llamar" para que te permitan hacer login o register. Pasaría igual con el `Storage` por ejemplo, no es necesario que entiendas como esta programado, importa saber como acceder a los archivos que guardas ahí.